# How to compare two values with jquery?

Tags: jquery, compare

i have to get them via a selector and add a class.

```
<div class="count_1">
<span class="percentage">10 %</span>
</div>
<div class="count_2">
<span class="percentage">90 %</span>
</div>


if (parseInt($(".count_1.percentage").value) > $(".count_2.percentage").value)) {
            blabla
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do:

```
if (parseInt($(".count_1 .percentage").html(), 10) > parseInt($(".count_2 .percentage").html(), 10))
```

Note that the space in the selector denotes child elements. `.count_1.percentage` matches elements with `class="count_1 percentage"`, wheareas `.count_1 .percentage` matches `class="percentage"` *within* `class="count_1"`

Also note the need to wrap both values in `parseInt`, and I also added a second parameter to the `parseInt` call which explicitly parses in base 10.

```
parseInt('08', 10); // 8
parseInt('08'); // 0
```

Comment: I'd use `text()` instead of `html()`, to strip out possible HTML tags. Probably doesn't matter in this case, though.

Comment: Also, I believe plain class selectors are quite slow. I'd add the element name: `$('div.count_1 > span')`.

Comment: good point, but yeah, the entire concept still makes heaps of assumptions about how the html code will look already

Comment: yeah, that's also a good point. again, depending on how many assumptions we can allow ourselves to make, i guess we might as well have done `var percentage = $('.percentage'); if(parseInt(percentage.eq(0).text(), 10) > parseInt(percentage.eq(1).text(), 10))` =) i don't really know what would be the fastest out of those

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. It would be better to use IDs for the wraper divs though ...

```
var val1 = parseInt ( $( '.percentage:first', $( '.count_1' ) ).html (), 10 );
var val2 = parseInt ( $( '.percentage:first', $( '.count_2' ) ).html (), 10 );

if ( val1 > val2 ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: converting a string value to int by `parseInt` feels a bit more conventional and readable than `* 1`, tho, so I don't see why you'd want to change that from the original example. it's also rids you the need for the replace since `parseInt('123abc')` will yield `123`

Comment: why have 2 calls to the jQuery object? `$('.count_1 .percentage')` is shorter and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

it's working, but i have multiple votingresult on the page.
i am calling the script everytime with a pollid as a selector.
but it's working only for the first pollresult.
any suggestions?

```
if (parseInt($(".pollid_1 .count1 .percentage").html(), 10) > parseInt($(".pollid_1 .count2 .percentage").html(), 10))
$(".pollid_1 .count1 span.percentage").addClass("selected");
else
$(".pollid_1 .count2 span.percentage").addClass("selected");

<div class="pollid_1">
<div class="count_1">
<span class="percentage">10 %</span>
</div>
<div class="count_2">
<span class="percentage">90 %</span>
</div>
</div>



if (parseInt($(".pollid_2 .count1 .percentage").html(), 10) > parseInt($(".pollid_2 .count2 .percentage").html(), 10))
$(".pollid_2 .count1 span.percentage").addClass("selected");
else
$(".pollid_2 .count2 span.percentage").addClass("selected");

<div class="pollid_2">
<div class="count_1">
<span class="percentage">10 %</span>
</div>
<div class="count_2">
<span class="percentage">90 %</span>
</div>
</div>
```

and so on...